# Flutter Google map marker with Ripple/Pulse animation

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I was trying to create a Ripple/Pulse animation for showing current location Flutter Google map. I have a .svg file and tried to load it to get the animation, but it's not working out. Image is showing but it's animation is not working.

Below is the code that i have used,

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(BuildContext context, String assetName) async {
    String svgString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assetName);
    //Draws string representation of svg to DrawableRoot
    DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = await svg.fromSvgString(svgString, null);
    ui.Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture();
    ui.Image image = await picture.toImage(26, 37);
    ByteData bytes = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
}

BitmapDescriptor descriptor = await _bitmapDescriptorFromSvgAsset(context, 'assets/marker.svg');
Marker marker = Marker(markerId: MarkerId(id.toString()), icon: descriptor, position: LatLng(lat, lon));
```

It's loading the image, but this will not help in showing the animation of svg.

I want something similar to the marker animation shown below in Google map(SVG/GIF or any other programatic way),

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/8c/55/c0/8c55c07c25fafad781765b4911c63894.gif

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Since the Marker is drawn by Maps, I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: @ErwanDaniel We can do the same in Native Android, so ideally there should be a way in Flutter as well, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, try this:
Install Spinkit flutter plugin at https://github.com/jogboms/flutter_spinkit.
Create a full-size container overlay widget and with the spinkit codes.

```html
class Overlay {
  static Widget show(BuildContext context) {
    
    final spinkit = SpinKitRipple(
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 150.0,
    );

    return Container(
      child: spinkit,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
    );
  }
}
```

And with the google map...

```html
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  GoogleMap googleMap = GoogleMap(
    markers: getMarkers(),
    initialCameraPosition: getInitial(),
    onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
    onCameraMoveStarted: onCameraMoveStarted,
    onCameraMove: onCameraMove,
    onCameraIdle: onCameraIdle
  );

  return Stack(children: <Widget>[
    googleMap,
    Overlay.show(context);
  ]);
}
```

I positioned the marker in the center with some adjustment and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will check and revert.

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_svg` does not support animations:

> ## Probably out of scope/non-goals
>
> SMIL animations. That just seems crazy. I think it'll be possible to animate the SVG but probably in a more Flutter driven way.

From [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#probably-out-of-scopenon-goals).

Comment: I was trying to show a Ripple Animation in Google Map marker, SVG/GIF or any other way, i have to animate it in Google map marker. As i'm not getting enough info for doing it, i just tried with SVG. If there is any other better option/solution to get the concerned result, please let me know.

Comment: I'll try to add an alternative way of animating to my answer.